# OpenCV assertion fail inside roi?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ofstream fout("E:\\FYP\\image analysis\\ImageAnalysis\\ImageAnalysis\\Cropped_Image\\Details.txt");

    Mat image = imread("rsz_2rsz_2iron-man.png", -1);

    //Declare global parameters
    int     kernel = 3;                     //to be input
    int     levels = 16;                    //to be input
    int     gap = 5;                        //to be input in mm
    double  depth_gap = 0.2;                //to be input in mm
    int     feedrate = 300;                 //to be input
    int     background = 0;
    int     width = image.cols;
    int     height = image.rows;
    double  x_window = width / kernel;
    double  y_window = height / kernel;
    int     x_anchor = 0;
    int     y_anchor = 0;
    double  height_threshold = 0;
    double  width_threshold = 0;

    int   max_img_width = 570; //in mm
    int   max_img_height = 480; //in mm

    cout << width << "x " << height << endl;
    cout << "(Physical Dimension    : " << x_window * gap << " mm x " << y_window *gap << " mm)" << endl << endl;

    height_threshold = ceil((y_window *gap) / max_img_height);
    width_threshold = ceil((x_window * gap) / max_img_width);

    int   width_panel = (x_window * gap) / width_threshold;
    int   height_panel = (y_window *gap) / height_threshold;
    int   no_panels = height_threshold * width_threshold;

    cout << "No. of panels = " << height_threshold * width_threshold << endl;
    cout << width_threshold << " (x-axis) x " << height_threshold << " (y-axis)" <<  endl << endl;

    cout << "Size of each panels : " << (x_window * gap) / width_threshold << "mm (x-axis) by " << (y_window *gap) / height_threshold << "mm (y-axis)" << endl << endl;

    //imshow("Original Image", image);

    int image_width = width / width_threshold;
    int image_height = height / height_threshold;

    cout << image_height << " vs " << image_width << endl;

    vector<Mat> smallImages;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += image_height)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += image_width)
        {
            Rect rect = Rect(x, y, image_width, image_height);
            smallImages.push_back(Mat(image, rect));
        }
    }


    //For displaying and saving cropped image
    for (int panel = 0; panel < no_panels; panel += 1)
    {
        string num_panel = to_string(panel);
        string filetype = ".png";
        string filename = "Image " + num_panel + filetype;
        //cout << num_panel << endl;
        //imshow(filename, smallImages[panel]);
        //waitKey(0);
        string location = "E:\\FYP\\image analysis\\ImageAnalysis\\ImageAnalysis\\Cropped_Image\\" + filename;
        imwrite(location, smallImages[panel]);
    }

    fout << "Kernel = " << kernel << endl;
    fout << "Levels = " << levels << endl;
    fout << "Gap = " << gap << endl;
    fout << "Max Height = " << max_img_width << endl;
    fout << "Max Width = " << max_img_height << endl;
    fout << "Number of Panels = " << height_threshold * width_threshold << endl;
    fout << "Size of each panels : " << (x_window * gap) / width_threshold << "mm (x-axis) by " << (y_window *gap) / height_threshold << "mm (y-axis)" << endl << endl;

    waitKey(0);
    system("PAUSE"); 
    //return 0;
}
```

This program is to devide big image into multiple image based on given max width and height and some other properties.

When I run the program with different kernel size, sometimes it gave out assertion fail and sometimes ok.

The error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 508
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 508
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 508
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 508
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 508
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting rectangles that are outside of the image. This is because of the wrong conditions in the `for` loops. Use:

```
 for (int y = 0; y <= (height - image_height); y += image_height)
 {
     for (int x = 0; x <= (width - image_width); x += image_width)
     {
          Rect rect = Rect(x, y, image_width, image_height);
          smallImages.push_back(Mat(image, rect));
     }
 }
```

Your original conditions are correct only when `height` and `width` are multiple of `image_height` and `image_width`, respectively.